# One program, 2 windows. How to notify #2 from #1 of change using observer?

Tags: java, observer-pattern

**Edit:** What I really want is: How to activate `update` from the second window, but from the first. I have added both `update`(s).

I have 2 windows, each windows has an observer. When I update anything within that window with an observer, it works!

However I'd like to also update the other window. I think my observer isn't right, no idea how to change it though

```
public class ObserverCtrl extends Observable {

    public ObserverCtrl(Secretariat window, ) {

        this.addObserver(window);
    }

    public ObserverCtrl(Comisie window) {

        this.addObserver(window);
    }



    public void refresh () {
        this.setChanged();
        this.notifyObservers();
    }

}
```

**Main file**

```
Secretariat window = new Secretariat();
Comisie window2 = new Comisie();
```

**Each JFrame (window) has**

```
private ObserverCtrl observer;
this.observer = new ObserverCtrl(this)
```

**First window, Secretariat**

```
@Override
public void update(Observable arg0, Object arg1) {
    candidat_TextField.setText(null);
    sectie_TextField.setText(null);
    codSectie_TextField.setText(null);
    confirmare_TextArea.setText(null);
    listModelCandidati.clear();
    listModelSectii.clear();
    loadSectiiListModel();
    loadCandidatiListModel();
}
```

**Second Window, Comisie**

```
@Override
public void update(Observable arg0, Object arg1) {
    this.loadSectiiListModel();

}
```

**I have an event click button in `Secretariat`. It activates `update()` for itself, I'd like it to also activate `update` for `Comisie`**

How should I have implemented thing so that informing window #2 from #1 via the Observer would have been possible ?

Comment: Smart, neither showing `addObserver()` or `notifyObservers()`...

Comment: No idea what you mean by any of that, sorry

Comment: We'll need to see what happens inside these, what you showed of your code is not helpful at all...

Comment: sounds like you are missing a Model and observing the View. Read something about the Model-View-Controller-Pattern.

Comment: @LukasKnuth Need more ? What exactly ? The actual button I click, or what ?

Comment: @Simulant Thank you for pointing that out, but I'd really need an answer on this, soon. I know that doesn't affect you, but if you'd be willing, I'll try my best to supply any information you'd need. If you can please help! thank you

Comment: The implementations of the methods i mentioned in my first comment.

Comment: @LukasKnuth Do you know how vague that is, I have no idea what you just said, again!

Comment: Seems like I'm speaking Spanish again... Post the code *inside* `addObserver()` and `notifyObservers()`

Comment: there ... isn't any. Those are java methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made another class that `extends Observable`, used that to notify Window #2